# ionic slider - lockSwipes(true) disables initialSlide and slideNext() methods?

Tags: angular, swipe, ionic3

Hi I'm using Ionic [Slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) to display todo lists and I want to disable the swipe guestures since my list items have them. Instead I want to change the slides via methods.

This is my component:

```
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

days: SbCalendarDay[] = [] //this is a list of todo's of each day

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
}

slide(direction:string){
    if(direction === 'prev'){
        this.slides.slidePrev()
    }else{
        this.slides.slideNext()
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
<div class="sb-calendar-day">
    <ion-slides [initialSlide]="1" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged($event)" (ionSlideWillChange)="slideWillChange($event)">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let day of days">
            <sb-list [list]="day.events" (sbListEvent)="listEvent($event)"></sb-list>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</div>
```

However when I lock the swipes, the `initialSlide` input doesn't work anymore. I'm starting off with an `array` of 3 days with `array[1]` being the current day.

Furthermore the methods `slideNext()` and `slidePrev()` also don't react.
Does `lockSwipes(true)` completely "lock down" the slider?

Is there a way to only disable the swiping gestures of the slider?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/slides/slides.ts) for `lockSwipes()`, it seems like the functions `slideNext` and `slidePrev` gets 'locked':

```
lockSwipes(shouldLockSwipes: boolean) {
    this._allowSwipeToNext = this._allowSwipeToPrev = !shouldLockSwipes;
}
```

The function ultimately ends up calling `slideTo`-function thats being imported from [`swiper.ts`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/slides/swiper/swiper.ts), where a check against `_allowSwipeToNext` and `_allowSwipeToPrev` is made:

```
// Directions locks
if (!s._allowSwipeToNext && translate < s._translate && translate < minTranslate(s)) {
    return false;
}
if (!s._allowSwipeToPrev && translate > s._translate && translate > maxTranslate(s)) {
    if ((s._activeIndex || 0) !== slideIndex ) return false;
}
```

`initialSlide`-input does not work is because in the function `initSwiper` imported from [`swiper.ts`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/slides/swiper/swiper.ts), the value of `initialSlide` is used as an argument to the function `slideTo`, and the `_allowSwipe[Next|Prev]` flags are checked.

For disabling only swipe gestures use [`onlyExternal`](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WYURF4jyhEY):

> `onlyExternal`: If true, then the only way to switch the slide is use of external API
>   functions like slidePrev or slideNext

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.slides.onlyExternal = true;
}
```

Comment: wow! Thats the best possible anwser with explanation i could've hoped for, thanks a ton!

Comment: Completely agree, amazing answer. +1

Comment: Absolutely awesome (and undocumented...)

Comment: Excellent explanation and solution! Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not sure how good a practice is using `setTimeout`. But, this hack worked for me.

```
setTimeout(()=> {
      this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
}, 100);
```

And template code:

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged($event)" [initialSlide]="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `allowTouchMove` Slide options to `false` like this :

template code :

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts">
```

ts code :

```
slideOpts = {
allowTouchMove: false
};
```