# Ionic 5 Angular: ion-slides horizontal sliding not working on device

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use ion-slides but it only works in the browser and not on iOS or Android devices. I can't slide between the slides.

** I have noticed that this problem only occurs when dynamic data is loaded. So if in ngOnInit() the necessary ArrayObject is filled with data. If the ArrayObject is static, then the whole thing works fine.

** As soon as I rotate my device/screen, i.e. the cross view, from that moment on the slider will also work.

Thank you!

HTML-File

```
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">

        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>

        <ion-title>?</ion-title>

      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>


    <ion-content class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding" style="--background: #f4f4f4">

      <ion-slides id="sliderDetail" #sliderDetail>
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let elem of elements">

          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2>{{elem.title}}</h2>
              <p>{{elem.content}}</p>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>

        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>

    </ion-content>
```

TS-File

```
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('sliderDetail', { static: false }) sliderDetail: IonSlides;

  elements: Array<any>;

  ...

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
}


async getData() {
    let ret = await Storage.get({ key: 'elements' });
    this.elements = await JSON.parse(ret.value);

    await this.sliderDetail.update();
    await this.sliderDetail.updateAutoHeight();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is:

```
setTimeout(()=> {
      this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
}, 300);
```

Further informations: [ionic-slider-lockswipestrue-disables-initialslide-and-slidenext-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516876/ionic-slider-lockswipestrue-disables-initialslide-and-slidenext-methods/45517166#comment107981499_45517166)